# Algorithm for a travel route (directed graph)

Tags: java, algorithm

For now, I get a list of unordered train tickets, I need to figure out where to start and where to stop and use "all" tickets to travel around. I am allowed to travel one city more than once (it's depending on my tickets). So How can I find an algorithm (pseudocode) for this tavel problem?

I was thinking to find the start point and ending point, however I don't know how to find the route which can use all tickets. Here is what I have done:

```
HashMap<String, List of tickets> outgoing = new HashMap<String, List of tickets>();
HashMap<String, Integer> incoming = new HashMap<String, Integer >();


For each ticket (t) in List {
    String start ==  t. origin
    String end  ==  t.destination
        If outGoing.contains(t) {
            outGoing.get(start).add(t);
            incoming.get(end)++;
        Else
            outGoing.put(start, EmptyList.add(t));
            inComing.put(end, 1);
        }
}

For each outGoing.Entry<String, List of tickets > entry: outGoing.entrySet()   
{
    String startingCity == “”;
    String endingCity == “”;

    String city = entry.getKey();

    If outGoing. get(city). size > inComing.get(city); {
        city == startingCity;
    }

    If outGoing. get(city). size < inComing.get(city); {
        city == endingCity;
    }
}

If (startingCity == “” && endingCity == “”) {
    //Start anywhere, because it is a cycle.
} else {
    //sort from startingCity to endingCity
}
```

Comment: Iterate your `List` of tickets, build a `Set` of destinations. Construct a *graph* connecting your unique destinations. Try and minimize the edges to some cost (generally something like distance traveled). This is usually called the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Actually the problem is much simpler than TSP. We are required to use each ticket once, not to visit each city only once.

Comment: @EyalSchneider Hi. I have read through the algorithm you shared with me. I have one concern about instead of delete one adjacency once a time, can I have loop delete them all and add all neighbors in the stack at one time? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all tickets have origins and destinations defined, and since you are required to use all of them, you are dealing with finding an [Eulerian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path).

The conditions for the existence of such path are:

1. The graph induced by all edges is connected
2. All nodes have in-degree=out-degree, except maybe two, where one has in-degree=out-degree+1 and the other has out-degree=in-degree+1

An efficient algorithm for this is described in http://www.graph-magics.com/articles/euler.php.

Comment: Hi. I have read through the algorithm you shared with me. I have one concern about instead of delete one adjacency once a time, can I have loop delete them all and add all neighbors in the stack at one time? Thank you!!

Comment: @JiahaoCai: What do you mean by "delete them all"? you still have to test at each step whether you are at a "dead end", or you can continue with some path. Also, when removing from the stack you can't assume that the complete path can be removed from the stack; you may have a fork to examine. Think of it as a DFS.